# Warning: unpack() when using cyrillic letters in MPDF60 library

Tags: php, mpdf

I use `MPDF60` library in my site to produce `PDF` files. When my site moved to another hosting I started to get this error message:

```
Warning: unpack() [function.unpack]: Type n: not enough input, need 2, have 0
```

And this error happens when there are cyrillic letters. By the way, if I test it locally or at another server, then everything is ok. So, I do not know what server settings may cause this error.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `mbstring.func_overload = 0` in PHP settings.

Comment: `unpack` is [not overloaded by mbstring](http://php.net/manual/en/mbstring.overload.php)

Comment: @Sjon, it's MPDF's typical error with cyrillic symbols if func_overload not set to 0. That solution is working, don't ask me why :).